# How to find the problem when a maven packaging stage last indefinitely?

Tags: maven, deadlock, maven-shade-plugin

I have a fairly large maven project that if compiled (using `mvn package` or `mvn install`), stuck on a packaging stage for 10+ hours:

```
[INFO] Building jar: /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/target/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.1.0:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ spookystuff-mldsl ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/target/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.1.0:test-jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ spookystuff-mldsl ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/target/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-test-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:test-jar (default) @ spookystuff-mldsl ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/target/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ spookystuff-mldsl ---
[INFO] Installing /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/target/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/peng/.m2/repository/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-mldsl/0.6.2-SNAPSHOT/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/.flattened-pom.xml to /home/peng/.m2/repository/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-mldsl/0.6.2-SNAPSHOT/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/target/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to /home/peng/.m2/repository/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-mldsl/0.6.2-SNAPSHOT/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/target/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to /home/peng/.m2/repository/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-mldsl/0.6.2-SNAPSHOT/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/target/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-test-sources.jar to /home/peng/.m2/repository/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-mldsl/0.6.2-SNAPSHOT/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-test-sources.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/peng/git-dev/scala-2.11/datapassports/spookystuff/mldsl/target/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar to /home/peng/.m2/repository/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-mldsl/0.6.2-SNAPSHOT/spookystuff-mldsl-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
(this is the last line of output)
```

The build output can be observed on CI server, with similar output:

https://app.codeship.com/projects/166836/builds/48698210?pipeline=103aace8-047a-47e4-9cb9-018c3ce0693a

I don't know what have caused this behaviour, but I suspect that a bug in maven-shade-plugin has caused dependency reduced pom generation to move into a indefinitely loop. How can I confirm this hypothesis collect enough evidence to report to the plugin maintainers?

Comment: It's a little bit strange to force someone to create a login to help you? Does your build work on plain command line? Which Maven version/Java version etc. you are using?